# Creating a 360 degree video in Sketchup

Tags: youtube, 360-degrees, virtual-reality

I know an architects firm who create walk through videos of their designs using Sketchup. So a 3D model of the designs are already in place, is there a way in Sketchup to create a 360 degree video that we can upload to Youtube.

The intention is for them to be able to show clients round their design using something like Google Cardboard etc. The camera would probably follow a slow track, but you could move you head and look round wherever you want.

This type of thing:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uG9vtckp1U

Just not Star wars.

Answer (score 1):

University of Minnesota VR lab had something called SketchupVR that mirrored sketchup through an OpenGL Renderer running.  They published it here.

http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~interran/acadia06.pdf

It was later extended to run using Elumenati's omnimap spherical camera library which does 360x180 rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Without being an expert in Sketchup, I'm pretty sure it can't do what you ask since it doesn't have the specific rendering capablities. More likely, the model is created in Sketchup and imported into a modelling/rendering package where the video is rendered.
If you don't have a commmercial package, you can do it in Blender (free, open source) for example.
What you want to do is render with an Equirectangular camera:
https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/camera.html

Answer (score 0):

> Without being an expert in Sketchup, I'm pretty sure it can't do what you ask 
>   since it doesn't have the rendering capablities.

I'm surprised nobody has corrected this in the past year. SketchUp does have rendering capabilities. It can render and export video of models in a few formats. See Lost In The Woods - https://vimeo.com/125412870

However, SU does not give a way to move subject or objects in the scene. My around that has been to insert jpg images, either by overlay or actually inserting them in the SU model.